# Different output between Powershell ToBase64String & Linux base64

Tags: c++, c, bash, powershell

SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ== I have to write two scripts, one for Windows Server and another for Ubuntu Server. To illustrate, if my bash script runs:

```
echo -n 'BASE64' | base64
```

the result is `QkFTRTY0`. If my PowerShell Script runs:

```
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes('BASE64'))
```

the result is `QgBBAFMARQA2ADQA`. Is important get the same PowerShell string in Linux. Anybody knows why this difference and some solution to my problem? I think that the problem is related to Unix's UTF-8 encoding, but I can't find a solution. I can decode the PowerShell output in Linux, but I can't encode a string in Linux and get the same result as PowerShell. A bash solution is optimal, but a C/C++ code solution or guide works too.

Comment: What about if you do `[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('BASE64'))`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I have to get the same result of `Unicode.GetBytes ` in Linux.

Comment: You can't get it to be the same because Linux uses utf8 and you are forcing Unicode and therefor have two different byte arrays. Why do you have the requirement to force Unicode encoding, using `UTF8.GetBytes` returns the correct result.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm forced to use Unicode.GetBytes, because I have to exchange the result of my Bash script with a propietary Windows software that seems use Unicode.GetBytes. I'm not sure, because I don't have access to the source code, but if I use the strings generated by PowerShell i can interact with it in Windows without problem. But I need to do the same on my Ubuntu Server.

Comment: OK, so your question is actually: "how do I convert a string to UTF-16 on Ubuntu, and how do I get the base64 of that?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `iconv` to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 without a byte order mark:

```
$ echo -n 'BASE64' | iconv -f UTF8 -t UTF16LE | base64
QgBBAFMARQA2ADQA
```

The `UTF16LE` causes it to omit the BOM.

See https://superuser.com/q/381056/4206, where someone asks about forcibly including the BOM, but you want the opposite, which -- conveniently -- is in the question.

Comment: With OSX 'iconv' the supported encoding switch is `UTF-16LE`. FWIW!